# How could I modify this Building Placement Code for an RTS (BGE)

Tags: python, game-engine

This code currently allows for buildings to be placed on flat surfaces (using an object as the Collision Detector).  It works fine for that, but how could I make it so that it can only be placed on one object like the plane (the ground of the map).  The reason for this is that right now you can place buildings on top of other buildings.  My map is flat so does not have any bumps or hills so I don't really need it nor want it to be placed on any flat surface.  Thanks!

```
from bge import logic

def main():
scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
cont = logic.getCurrentController()

mouse_over = cont.sensors["MouseOver"]

if mouse_over.positive and scene.objects["Arrow"]['ActiveYesNo?'] :
tracker = scene.objects["Arrow"]
tracker.worldPosition = mouse_over.hitPosition
tracker.worldPosition.z += 1
```

Comment: A picture on what or how this code works with your game or the game engine would be helpful! :D

Comment: I think you were following my answer about a grid snapping RTS system. Try looking at this answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28313/5426

Comment: @X-27 I was actually using your answer.  I just don't know how I could modify it so the tracker only goes on the plane.

Comment: Use this kind of setup (apparently you didn't follow my answer very closely) http://i.stack.imgur.com/7M0pp.png just use that same property on your ground. Property **MouseTracking**

Comment: @X-27 I don't think I explained this good enough.  It lets you place buildings on ANY flat surface.  I need it just so they can be placed only on the ground.  Maybe by somehow limiting the tracker to only move along the X and Y axis, but not to jump up on top of another building and allow it to be placed there.

Comment: Exactly!!!! only put the property of MouseTracking on the objects you want it to track to.

Comment: OH!!!!!! Ok I feel stupid now, Thank you!